# How do I pass in more than one parameter to the onChange action for the select element in Ember2.3

Tags: ember.js, ember.js-2

I have a **select** element within a loop, and the action I want to be triggered needs to have two parameters: the selected option of the **select** element and the item we are looping with. My code looks like so:

```
{{#each loopItems as |loopItem|}}
 <select onChange={{action 'fireThis' loopItem target.value }}> 
  {{#each loopItem.subItems as |subItem|}}
    <option value={{subItem.id}}>{{subItem.value}}</option>
  {{/each}}
 </select>
{{/each}}
```

And my **fireThis** action is like so:

```
fireThis:function(loopItem, value){
 //Do something here with both. 
 // like loopItem.set('thisProperty', value);
}
```

So, in my particular case, the number of subItems is dynamic, and I need to use the selected subItem with the loopItem it is currently under.

Barring refactoring into components (right now, I cannot do that), how would I pass in more than one parameter to the action fired on 'onChange'?

I have tried:

```
<select onChange={{action 'fireThis' value ="loopItem target.value" }}> 
<select onChange={{action 'fireThis' value ="loopItem target.value" }}>
<select onChange={{action 'fireThis' loopItem value="target.value"}}>
<select onChange={{action 'fireThis' value="target.value" loopItem}}>
```

For all of the above, both my params in the function are undefined (or cause another error). The only one that works is:

```
<select onChange={{action 'fireThis' value="target.value"}}>
```

But that only gives me the subItem, not the loopItem.

Unfortunately, the loopItems are newly created Ember Objects, void of any ID parameters, so I cannot give each select element a unique ID either. The ability to pass more than one parameter would pretty much solve my entire problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A bit late, but the answer found here works:
[ember 2 parameters in a action of a select menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36291998/ember-2-parameters-in-a-action-of-a-select-menu).

For OP's solution you wrap it like so:

`<select onChange={{action (action 'fireThis' loopItem) value="target.value"}}>`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<select onChange={{action 'fireThis' loopItem}}>

fireThis:function(loopItem){
 var value = this.$('option:selected').val();
 //Do something here with both. 
 // like loopItem.set('thisProperty', value);
}
```

Comment: Tried that too (missed it out on the question, my bad.) In this case, the loopItem comes through fine, but the value parameter is undefined. With 'target.value', the value is 'target.value' as a string.

Comment: This is a view, not a component? You might need `view.target.value`

Answer (score 0):

I decided to -as they say- bite the bullet and wrap the entire thing into a component. I passed each loopitem into the component + all required objects to make things work, then inside the component, I used value="target.value".

My refactored code looks like this now:

```
{{#each loopItems as |loopItem|}}
   {{loop-item-component loopItem=loopItem}}
{{/each}}
```

--

```
// Loop-item-component

    <select onChange={{action 'fireThis' value='target.value' }}> 
      {{#each loopItem.subItems as |subItem|}}
        <option value={{subItem.id}}>{{subItem.value}}</option>
      {{/each}}
    </select>
```

Within the component, then, I put the action:

```
actions:{
 ...
    fireThis:function(value){
      let loopItem = this.get('loopItem');
      // Do something here with both. 
      // like loopItem.set('thisProperty', value);
    }
}
```

I have not been able to try out the other suggested answers so far, but as soon as I do, I will post the results here; it would still be useful to learn how to pass multiple parameters to an action triggered by a change in the options of a select element.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass more than one parameter then I would encourage not to use `value="target.value"`. if you use that it will get `target.value` from first argument `event` object.

```
<select onchange={{action 'fireThis' loopItem}}>
```

and in `firethis` action, you will receive `loopItem` and `event` object in the parameter.

```
actions:{
 firethis(loopItem,event)
 {
  //let selectedValue= event.tager.value;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the second argument in the template like this.

```
  <PowerSelect
    @selected={{this.selectedPrice}}
    @options={{this.priceRange}}
    @onChange={{fn this.choosePrice "minPrice"}}
    class="w-64"
    as |price|
  >
    {{price.title}}
  </PowerSelect>
```

Then create your function to handle the click:

```
  @action
  choosePrice(type, price) {
    // type will be 'minPrice'
    // price will be the option you selected
  }
```