# ember 2 parameters in a action of a select menu

Tags: javascript, ember.js, parameters, components

I'm trying to pass more than one argument in an ember action.
The problem is that one of the arguments is value='target.value' and apparently Ember doesn't like to add a second one.

How can I pass these two parameters? 
value='target.value' works if I only need one argument.

I've tried to write it this way but category is undefined.

```
{{#each selectorsData as |selectorItem|}}
<select onchange={{ action selectorItem.action value='target.value' category='selectorItem.name' }}>
```

I've tried this way too, but Ember gives me an error

```
{{#each selectorsData as |selectorItem|}}
   <select onchange={{ action selectorItem.action value='target.value' selectorItem.name }}>

 Error: Parse error on line 4:
 ....value' selectorItem.name }}>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To accomplish this you must use closure actions.
[Reference to Invoking Action](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#toc_invoking-an-action)

Controller

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  appName: 'Ember Twiddle',
  selectorsData: [
    { name: 'mike', value: '1', action: 'alert', options: ["1", "2"] },
    { name: 'steve', value: '2', action: 'alert', options: ["1", "2"]  }
  ],

  actions: {
    alert(value, name, target) {
      alert("Hello: " + value + " - " + name + "-" + target);
    }
  }

});
```

Template

```
<h1>Welcome to {{appName}}</h1>
<br>
<br>
{{outlet}}
<br>
<br>
{{#each selectorsData as |selectorItem|}}
    <label>{{selectorItem.name}}</label>
   <select onchange={{action (action selectorItem.action selectorItem.value selectorItem.name) value="target.value"}}>
        {{#each selectorItem.options as |option|}}
        <option value={{option}}>{{option}}</option
      {{/each}}
   </select>
   <br>
{{/each}}
```

[Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/830a011d23b3419f5156cd63d257194f?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C)

Comment: no, value='target.value' returns the selection inside the selector as an argumment

Comment: ah yea I see what you mean now

Comment: Any idea?  I can't see any way around... :S

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<select onchange={{action selectorItem.action target.value selectorItem.name}}>

....

yourAction: function(targetValue, selectorItemName) {..}
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/nvfm3yz1/

Comment: Pat, thanks for your answer but it is still not working, your solution returns  undefined for 'value'