# Ember: set attribute's value with action passed from a <select> element

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, html-select

I'm trying to figure out how to set a new Ember Data Record's attribute's value based on choices in a select element, using the {{action}} helper. Here's my situation, simplified:

**item.js route**. Creates a new record that is available in the template.

```
model() {
  return this.store.createRecord('item');
}
```

**new-item.hbs template**. The select-element triggers the action to set the new item's color attribute.

```
<select {{action 'setColor' model value="target.value" on="change"}}>
  <option value="">choose</option>
  <option value="white">white</option>
  <option value="blue">blue</option>
  <option value="red">red</option>
  <option value="yellow">yellow</option>
</select>
```

**item.js controller**.

```
actions: {
  setColor(item, option) {
    console.log(option);
    record.set('color', option);
    console.log(item);
  }
}
```

Console.log(option) returns nothing. The record.set works fine, I can hardcode the option and the console.log(item) will show that the new item object has the color attribute set.

On the other hand, if I do the action call with just

```
onChange={{action 'setColor' value="target.value"}}
```

the color gets logged correctly from the action. But if I add "model" into that action call as before with the {{action ... on="change"}} syntax, console.log(option) returns undefined and console.log(item) returns an Event with no model object attached.

**Question is:** How do I pass *both* the target.value *and* the model to the setColor action?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`setColor` function will receive `event` attribute as last argument by default.

```
onChange={{action 'setColor' value="target.value"}}
```

so  `value` attribute will be retrieved from `event`. so this will work as expected. but

```
onChange={{action 'setColor' model value="target.value"}}
```

`value` attribute will try to get `target.value` from `model` property as we sent `model` as first argument, and default `event` argument will be passed as second argument. so combining won't work.

Solution would be

```
onChange={{action 'setColor' model}}
```

and inside actions,

```
actions: {
  setColor(model, event) {
    let value = event.target.value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually `event` passed as second argument

Comment: Yes. it's always passed as last argument

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue, but was not satisfied with the accepted answer here, since I had 2 different inputs (dropdown & text-field) that used the same action (but not same path to resolve the value), so I had to use `value="..."` as part of the action helper.

I found the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/45762071/45948

so in your case it would be:

```
onChange={{action (action 'setColor' model) value="target.value"}}
```

and then simply:

```
actions: {
  setColor(model, option) {
    ...
  }
}
```